# how to truncate HTML string without leaving it malformated?

Tags: c#

I have to display first N (for example say 50 or 100) characters out of entire html string. I have to display well formated html.If i apply simple substring that will get me a malformated html string 
E.g.

Sample string : `"<html><body><a href="http://foo.com">foo</a></body></html>"`

trucated string: `"<html><body><a href="http://foo.com">foo<"`

This will get me malformated html :(

Any ideas on how to achieve this ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) - it will parse out the HTML for you, but you will need to figure out how to produce a truncated version yourself. It should make things a lot easier though.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the HTML into a DOM tree. Start with the deepest/innermost elements and

- remove the content of the innermost node, or the node if it has no content
- check the string length.

Rinse, lather, repeat.

This may truncate your string to the empty string, if your desired length is small enough.

For extra kicks, you could try removing *attributes* of the nodes as you go.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some forum systems simply append a </b></u></i></s> after every single post.  You could approach this in a similar fashion.

Of course, its ugly and it wouldn't fix that trailing <

That is by far the simplest method.  Better method would actually be generating a tree and... kicking nodes off until you meet the requirement.

Comment: do you mean identifying missing end tags and adding them programmatically?